# Wrap label's height if is null or empty

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using a listview and inside two Labels

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="list" HasUnevenRows="True"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>

                            <Label BackgroundColor="Gainsboro" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label BackgroundColor="Wheat" Text="{Binding Comments}" />

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

When Comments is null or empty. My Label it keeps it's height. I need to wrap height if is null or empty
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataTrigger` to hide this `Label` element. I assume that your `Comments` property has a default value eg. `Comments=""` because otherwise it will be null and the trigger won't work like you expect.

```
...
<Label BackgroundColor="Wheat" Text="{Binding Comments}" >
  <Label.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                     Binding="{Binding Path=Comments.Length}" Value="0">
              <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
          </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
...
```

If in the `Comments` property you have `null` value you can use the following code:

```
...
<Label BackgroundColor="Wheat" Text="{Binding Comments}" >
  <Label.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Comments, TargetNullValue=''}" Value="">
              <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
          </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
...
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, it work like a charm! Is there any way to check if it is null instead of length?

Comment: Where is all this knowledge hidden?

Comment: Please check my answer again. I have added code that works with null values. You can achieve this requirement by using `TargetNullValue` in the `DataTrigger` binding and compare it to the empty string.